# Question about copying and deleting (cp, rm) in UNIX

Tags: c, file-io, linux-kernel, operating-system

Lecture notes often present us with questions which we have to solve ourselves for practice, I'm having trouble with this one and can't seem to find an answer to it.

---

*Assume a unix filesystem with a superblock, lists of free/occupied/deleted blocks, inodes and hierarchical file directories and datablocks*

*What happens in the above structures if we*

- copy a file using **cp**
- delete a file using **rm**

---

I believe I understand what occurs in the superblock for both instances but with the rest I am not sure and cannot seem to find an answer, neither in my lectures notes nor online.

Comment: I think it will be good, if you try to "answer" yourself, so that we understand better which part you do not understand (and the level of the lecture). Feel free to add ??? on the part you do not know or you are not sure. Note: the question can be tricky if origin and destination are in different filesystem, but I assume this is not supposed to be so. Maybe start from the last point and go back.